# How do I document an accessor function with the same name as a Q_PROPERTY?

Tags: c++, qt, doxygen

**TL;DR:** How can I generate doxygen documentation for an accessor that has the same name as a property declared with `Q_PROPERTY`?

---

Qt's [property system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) makes it possible to use Qt's meta-object-system on given properties:

```
// example class and documentation
class Widget : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(int size READ size WRITE setSize NOTIFY sizeChanged)

public:
  Widget(QObject * parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent){}
  int size() const;

public slots:
  void setSize(int new_size);

signals:
  void sizeChanged(int); //!< signals a size change

private:
  int m_size = 0; //!< the Widget's size, see #size.
};
```

If one now uses doxygen in the implementation

```
//! @property size is the size of our widget

//! @brief Set the widget's size to @a new_size.
void Widget::setSize(int new_size) { 
  if(new_size != m_size) {
    m_size = new_size; 
    emit sizeChanged(m_size);
  }
}

//! @brief Returns the widget's size.
int Widget::size() const {
  return m_size;
}
```

Only `setSize`'s documetaion gets generated correctly. `size()`'s documentation gets mistaken for the *property's* documentation. The code above acts as if

```
//! @property size
//! @brief Returns the widget's size.
int Widget::size() const {
  return m_size;
}
```

was used. Neither `@fn Widget::size()const` nor any other doxygen special command seems to help: `size()`'s generated documentation stays empty and ends up in the `size` (property) documentation instead.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Maybe the examples in the Configuration chapter, paragraph Examples can give you a hint. See the PREDEFINED part.

Comment: @albert doxygen --version is 1.8.11. The "trick" in the doxygen manual section works, but will remove the property documentation alltogether, whether I would like to have _both_. But that's most likely [not possible](https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/trouble.html), I guess.

Comment: I think the basic problem might be signaled by: ".../aa.cpp:6: warning: member with no name found.", this is the property documentation line. I didn't see a solution yet. (In the doxygen code around the message the following is present: "// this should not be called".

Comment: Looks like when documenting the function and property in the include file / class definition it is OK so something like: 
  //! is the size of our widget
  Q_PROPERTY(int size READ size WRITE setSize NOTIFY sizeChanged) and 
  //! Returns the widget's size.
  int size() const;

Comment: Did you try the suggestion of documenting the Q_PROPERTY in the .h file instead of the .cpp file?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work. That was my original variant, by the way, before I moved `//! @property` into the implementation.

Comment: Did you have the \property in the .h file, as that didn't work for me either (and was not necessary when documenting straight in front of the Q_PROPERTY)

Comment: I have tried both variants. If you have a working solution please provide an answer, as comments are sub-par for code discussions.

Comment: When I have again access to the computer with the example I have I'll see if I can post it (will take some days)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/2009) or rather unimplemented feature. As of today, it's not possible to document a property and a getter if they have the same name. The getter's documentation will always end up in the property's one.

The reason for this is `doxygen`'s `findmember` implementation. If you use `doxygen -d findmembers` you can see that both `size` (the property) and `size()` (the function) "match":

```
findMemberDocumentation(): root->type=`int' root->inside=`' root->name=`Widget::size' root->args=`() const ' section=6000000 root->spec=0 root->mGrpId=-1
findMember(root=0x197efe0,funcDecl=`int Widget::size() const ',related=`',overload=0,isFunc=1 mGrpId=-1 tArgList=(nil) (#=0) spec=0 lang=200
findMember() Parse results:
  namespaceName=`'
  className=`Widget`
  funcType=`int'
  funcSpec=`'
  funcName=`size'
  funcArgs=`() const'
  funcTempList=`'
  funcDecl=`int Widget::size'
  related=`'
  exceptions=`'
  isRelated=0
  isMemberOf=0
  isFriend=0
  isFunc=1

1. funcName=`size'
2. member name exists (2 members with this name)
3. member definition found, scope needed=`Widget' scope=`Widget' args=`' fileName=/tmp/test/example.cpp
4. class definition Widget found
5. matching `'`() const' className=Widget namespaceName=
6. match results of matchArguments2 = 1
```

You can even reproduce this with another non-`const` variant `int size()`. You will end up with three members that have the same name. Doxygen cannot handle properties and functions with the same name at the moment and does not document the getters in this case.

If you don't need the property documentation, you can disable the `Q_PROPERTY` macro in your `Doxyfile` (as [documented](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#config_examples)):

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING  = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION       = YES
PREDEFINED            = Q_PROPERTY(x)=
```

That way the lexer won't scan `Q_PROPERTY`.

Answer (score 0):

As promised:
The differences to the original code is that the documentation is not placed in the implementation file but in the include file.

The include file:

```
// example class and documentation
class Widget : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  //! size is the size of our widget
  Q_PROPERTY(int size READ size WRITE setSize NOTIFY sizeChanged)

public:
  //! Set the widget's size to @a new_size.
  Widget(QObject * parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent){}
  //! Returns the widget's size.
  int size() const;

public slots:
  void setSize(int new_size);

signals:
  void sizeChanged(int); //!< signals a size change

private:
  int m_size = 0; //!< the Widget's size, see #size.
};
```

The implementation file:

```
void Widget::setSize(int new_size) {
  if(new_size != m_size) {
    m_size = new_size;
    emit sizeChanged(m_size);
  }
}

int Widget::size() const {
  return m_size;
}
```

Difference in the doxygen configuration file (`Doxyfile`, probably a few to many set to YES):

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = YES
```

Comment: While "as promised", the answer itself does not contain the differences. Please include _all_ explanation in the answer itself, as a comment chain can get deleted at any point.

Comment: Also, this only works if `size()` (the method) is documented in the header, which should also get mentioned in the answer.